# How do I construct a public key from a modulus and exponent given as a hex-encoded string?

Tags: rust, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a password with the following modulus:

```
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
```

And the exponent:

```
010001
```

I have to convert them somehow into an array of bytes, I am very new to this so I haven't had much success as far.

I have tried using `hex::decode()` to no avail.

```
let publickey_mod = "cc7e2fe78c235b7eff9beb63696dbbf565b04b26902d7b1133813821e614da7b0a694a17a564192de3389adc1ab705642f966a120ef74ace060f8eeb53a91d1bbc98a3ed9f53f5a40d3cc814da56ad5ba8581b7e96b6827bf323706d1836985ac9783d6dcd5c7291a4f84ca9f04a0194fab8bde7b97d15153eb3f5034eb12ef7e2e696beb7d2570e42f3bf5494622f05c0499c47eb8c23f324eac763a924e6ad540906788d571cc6b2536d2e039cf280e6e21616bf26b82e79b28079127a9f92cf04dc9d18f418c637039be6ee4ba9fdee3cbaf3381cce5409277aa18821e61a9ef14c21028f31ae7b2eadd7be4e298d37a47acc0b7c8af3c48ec7aeca8b6111";
let publickey_exp = "010001"; 
let pass = "TestPass120";
let modnum = BigNum::from_slice(hex_to_bytes(publickey_mod.clone()).as_slice())?;
let expnum = BigNum::from_slice(hex_to_bytes(publickey_exp.clone()).as_slice())?;
let key = Rsa::from_public_components(modnum, expnum)?;
let mut encrypted = vec![0; key.size() as usize];
key.public_encrypt(pass.as_bytes(), &mut encrypted, openssl::rsa::Padding::PKCS1)?;
let encoded = base64::encode(&encrypted);

fn hex_to_bytes(hex: String) -> Vec<u8> {
    // some code that translates hex string to bytes and returns it
}
```

The expected results would be a `Vec<u8>` with bytes that I can supply to `BigNum::from_slice`.

Comment: You should provide a complete working example of your code so people can understand better what you are trying to do. Anyway, it is possible to get a slice of bytes from a `String` or `str` using the `as_bytes` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't recommend passing a `String`, rather a `&str` reference, because the former would move the string into the function, which is not necessary in this case.
With this, you do not need to clone the string anymore, simply because your two variables are `&'static str` to begin with.

The `hex_to_bytes` function could be built like this:

```
fn hex_to_bytes(hex: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    hex.as_bytes()
        .chunks(2)
        .filter_map(|b| std::str::from_utf8(b).ok())
        .filter_map(|s| u8::from_str_radix(s, 16).ok())
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a735645f5ff0a2d5ec0c166f7824fb29)

It iterates on pair of bytes in the string, converts each pair to a &str which is then converted into an u8.

Invalid conversions are simply discarded.

It can be called like this:

```
let modnum = BigNum::from_slice(hex_to_bytes(publickey_mod).as_slice())?;
let expnum = BigNum::from_slice(hex_to_bytes(publickey_exp).as_slice())?;
```

Finally, assuming you are using the openssl crate, there is an even simpler solution, using [openssl::bn::from_hex_str](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.9.11/openssl/bn/struct.BigNum.html#method.from_hex_str):

```
let modnum = BigNum::from_hex_str(publickey_mod)?;
let expnum = BigNum::from_hex_str(publickey_exp)?;
```